# how to mount a shared windows folder into a docker application

Tags: windows, docker, go, share, mount

I need to access my windows shared folder inside a container.
I'm providing my code and enviroment details hoping some one figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

Shared folder in windows:
`E:\share`

[image]

- Everyone with full control
- Using windows 11. Logged with a microsoft account linked with my e-mail.
- The IP address in the volume creation is the ip address of my machine in my private network.
- The shared folder and the docker deamon are at the same machine.

My simple go program:
groupshare.go (go version 1.19)

```golang
    package main

    func main() {
      // just keep the container running... silly code
      reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
      fmt.Print("Type something: ")
      command, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
      fmt.Println("you typed:", command)
    }
```

Dockerfile:

```bash
    FROM golang:1.16

    COPY groupshare.go go.mod /app/

    WORKDIR /app

    RUN go mod download

    RUN go build -o main

    CMD ["./main"]
```

volume creation:"

`docker volume create --driver local --opt type=cifs --opt device=//DESKTOP-TMA/share --opt o=addr=192.168.15.46,username=DESKTOP-TMA/anyUser,password=******,domain=DESKTOP-TMA,vers=3.0 sharevolume`

docker build command:

```
docker build -t groupshare .
```

docker run command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v sharevolume:/mnt/share  groupshare
```

result:

permission denied:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/sharevolume/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //DESKTOP-TMA/share:/var/lib/docker/volumes/sharevolume/_data, data: addr=192.168.15.46,username=DESKTOP-TMA/totalys,password=********,domain=DESKTOP-TMA,vers=3.0: permission denied.
```

I have tryed creating new windows users and addinf specific permissions at the shared folder but got no result. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: AFAICT this question has nothing to do with the Go language so I do understand why the `go` tag is present.

Comment: Well, I started writing the mount process inside the go program in the first place, but after researching a little I found some hints about doing it in the docker command... I let the go part because it may help someone to think in a solution in the go program...